# How can I implement webviews in different layouts without having to make a class for every layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, webview

okey, so i have a main class with 8 buttons, and i have each button to setcontentview layout 1, 2, etc.. I have implemented webviews with different IDs in each of the layouts, but i can seem to get it to work. The plan is to show a picture from a website in each layout, and since im not great at programming, i thought i'd try this first. Here's my questions: How can i make this setup work (in terms that i understand), and what's the most optimal way to get this result? I get nullpointererror.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


 Button btn1, btn2, //etc..;
 WebView webview_1, webview_2, //etc..;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);


    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    //and so on

    WebView one = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    one.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    one.loadUrl("www.example.com/jpg);

    WebView two = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
    two.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    two.loadUrl("www.example.com/jpg);

 //etc
 }

public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
    return;
case R.id.button2:
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    return;
//etc

}

//main_layout

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="450dip"
    android:layout_height="450dip"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/norge"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="150dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/overskrift_velg_sensor"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    tools:context=".Main" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:autoLink="web"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:autoLink="web"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/button2" />
</LinearLayout>

//layout1

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Object"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<WebView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:id="@+id/webview1"
 android:layout_weight="4">

 </WebView>

 </LinearLayout>

 //layout2

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Object2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <WebView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:id="@+id/webview2"
 android:layout_weight="4">

 </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `setContentView()` once in the `onCreate()` method of your activity. Subsequent calls to the method will have no effect.

I suggest that you have just one WebView, and when you click a button, you change the URL of the WebView with the `loadUrl()` method.